# Encountered typical issue with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have encounter typical issue when using jQuery, as per below code the _hideIconChild() will be called whenever I click other selectors in toolbox. During debugging, it goes to the _hideIconChild() and execute it but it is not hiding the overflow component. If I try it in the console `colorPickerComp.hide()` it hides. I don't understand why it is not working in the function. Anyone as a clue?

```
var colorPickerComp = $(".colorpicker");


/**
 * Hide anything that overflowing on the screen when clicked 
 */

function _hideIconChild() {
    colorPickerComp.hide();
       }
```

Comment: `$(".colorpicker"));` extra `)`

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to call `_hideIconChild` function:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zSdUb/)

```
var colorPickerComp = $(".colorpicker");

/**
 * Hide anything that overflowing on the screen when clicked 
 */

function _hideIconChild() {
  $(this).hide();
}
```

To hide it upon clicking:

```
$(".colorpicker").click(_hideIconChild);
```

Comment: my question is when executing the _hideIconChild() it needs to hide but it is not happening

Comment: I cannot bind click to each selector and I cannot just write $(this).hide() because I need to hide few more components when executing _hideIconChild().

Comment: You can bind it to `$("*")` which will target all the elements or add some special class `$(".hideable")`. You are also not forced to use `this`, you can safely put `$(".colorpicker").hide()` in the handler function body.

Comment: I just want to figure out why it is not working the way I was trying. Even when I call the function it is not hiding

Comment: Are those in the same context? Is colorpickercomp global?

Comment: They are within same function scope.

Comment: Please show the full code. Including where you call the function.